# How to union only those rows (from large table) with keys in left small table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, union

I have two dataframe, one is large, the other is small:

```
val small_df = sc.parallelize(List(("Alice", 15), ("Bob", 20)).toDF("name", "age")

val large_df = sc.parallelize(("Bob", 40), ("SomeOne", 50) , ... ).toDF("name", "age")
```

I want to add up these two dataframe but only those with the key in my small table, that is, I want my result to be like:

```
List(("Alice", 15), ("Bob", 60))
```

My first attempt is try to do `union` and `reduceByKey`, but I can't seem to find a way to `union` two tables and keep those rows with keys in the smaller one only.

Is there a way to do something like "left union" or other way to approach my answer?

Comment: performing a left join, with the small_df first will maintain the keys of you small dataframe, if you always have tuples in both dfs, you should be able to reduce the two values by key. Problematic could be duplicate keys on the small_df. However, you simply might deduplicate the small_df in a first step in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem would be to make an outer join and then sum the two resulting age columns together. Note that `spark.implicits._` should be imported for use of `$` and `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast` for the broadcast.

If any of the two dataframes contains duplicates (in the name column) the final dataframe will contains duplicates as well, which could be what you want or not. For duplicates in `large_df` those will only show up if there is a corresponding name in `small_df`, as specified in the question.

As an optimization, as one of the dataframes are small it can be broadcasted before the join to increase the performance.

```
val small_df = sc.parallelize(List(("Alice", 15), ("Bob", 20)).toDF("name", "age")
val large_df = sc.parallelize(("Bob", 40), ("SomeOne", 50)).toDF("name", "age")

val df = large_df.withColumnRenamed("age", "large_age").join(broadcast(small_df), Array("name"), "right_outer")
val df2 = df.withColumn("age", when($"large_age".isNotNull, $"age" + $"large_age").otherwise($"age")).select("name", "age")
df2.show

+-----+----+
| name| age|
+-----+----+
|Alice|15.0|
|  Bob|60.0|
+-----+----+
```

Comment: I agree, this is a faster solution than a group by. But I think we should keep the bigger dataframe on the left side, so that the small dataframe can be broadcasted.

Comment: You are correct, I added the broadcast of the smaller dataframe to the code.

Comment: Fantastic! A pure SQL solution, that's what I want! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That should give you what you want:

```
val existingKeys = small_df.
  join(large_df, "name").
  select($"name", large_df("age"))
val all = small_df.
  union(existingKeys).
  groupBy("name").
  agg(sum("age") as "age")
scala> all.show
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|  Bob| 60|
|Alice| 15|
+-----+---+
```

Comment: I don't use DataFrames, but isn't there a left join operator?

Comment: You **do** use DataFrames since you `sc.parallelize(List(("Alice", 15), ("Bob", 20)).toDF`. That gives you a DataFrame.

Comment: I am not the one who asked the OP :)

Comment: Why are you asking about left join operator? Would that make the query more efficient? There's left join and you can specify join type as the 3rd input parameter to `join`.

Comment: I am not sure about efficiency, it simply seems more natural to me. Thanks, I was just curious